# Best way to compare files for updates in c++?

Tags: c++, ftp, md5, libcurl

I have a task where I need to look for updates between a bunch of files on server and a bunch of files on local computer. I am totally at loss here, what way will be the best and fastest ?

I am planning on using libcurl with c++ to log on to ftp.

Comment: So, are you trying to compare two files (one on the server and one on your local computer) and see what the differences are?

Comment: Presumably you cannot use an existing mechanism that's reasonably tried and tested, such as robocopy or rsync?

Comment: what I am trying to do, is see if files on local comp and on server are same or if some files are changed, and download only files which are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends a bit about other factors like if others but one way could be to create a directory structure where the date is the directory name. The advantage of this its easy to find what belongs to a particular update and you can sort the directories after name e.g. yyyymmdd. You just need to remember when the last update was, you can also include a file with information about changes and a version number to make it extra user friendly.

Normally a release may consist of several new files so keeping them together under the same umbrella may be a good idea instead of updating each individual file since after some time it may make it complicated to remember what fits together.

Comment: Andres, Information file option sounds more like what I need in the current situation. So simple and yet I couldn't think of it :) Thanks a lot.